# Why are some of my controls positioned slightly off in a dialog template in a resource file, particularly in the Y direction?

Tags: winapi

I am constructing my own color selection dialog, and I have finished laying out all the controls in my dialog template. However, there is one weird thing I'm noticing:

[image: Screenshot]

Notice how there's extra vertical space between the H and S edit controls, and the R and G edit controls, than there are between any other two edit controls.

The H, S, and V edits in my resource file are

```
    EDITTEXT        rcH, 238, 78, 30, 14, ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    EDITTEXT        rcS, 238, 92, 30, 14, ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    EDITTEXT        rcV, 238, 106, 30, 14, ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
```

so I would assume they would tightly hug. Why don't they? Is it a rounding issue with the dialog unit conversion? I tried different font sizes but didn't notice a change.

And in fact, why do the edges of all the edit fields overlap slightly? I would assume two edit controls next to each other wouldn't overlap; if I change the font from Segoe 9 to Segoe 8 the text fields actually *flicker* when tabbing between them due to the overlap.

This is on Windows 7 x64, which is my minimum requirement. This dialog will most likely be run with the `DialogBoxParam()` function, but I doubt which function I use would be the issue...? Right now I'm just using `DialogBox()`.

Thanks!

```
#define rcColorDialog 102

#define rcFontSamplePlacement 1003

#define rcColorSVChooser 1100
#define rcColorHSlider 1101
#define rcPreview 1102
#define rcOpacitySlider 1103
#define rcH 1104
#define rcS 1105
#define rcV 1106
#define rcRDouble 1107
#define rcRInt 1108
#define rcGDouble 1109
#define rcGInt 1110
#define rcBDouble 1111
#define rcBInt 1112
#define rcADouble 1113
#define rcAInt 1114
#define rcHex 1115
#define rcHLabel 1116
#define rcSLabel 1117
#define rcVLabel 1118
#define rcRLabel 1119
#define rcGLabel 1120
#define rcBLabel 1121
#define rcALabel 1122
#define rcHexLabel 1123

rcColorDialog DIALOGEX 13, 54, 344, 209
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | DS_3DLOOK
CAPTION "Color"
FONT 9, "Segoe UI"
BEGIN
    // this size should be big enough to get at least 256x256 on font sizes >= 8 pt
    CTEXT       "AaBbYyZz", rcColorSVChooser, 7, 7, 195, 195, SS_NOPREFIX | SS_BLACKRECT

    // width is the suggested slider height since this is vertical
    CTEXT       "AaBbYyZz", rcColorHSlider, 206, 7, 15, 195, SS_NOPREFIX | SS_BLACKRECT

    LTEXT       "Preview:", -1, 230, 7, 107, 9, SS_NOPREFIX
    CTEXT       "AaBbYyZz", rcPreview, 230, 16, 107, 20, SS_NOPREFIX | SS_BLACKRECT

    LTEXT       "Opacity:", -1, 230, 45, 107, 9, SS_NOPREFIX
    CTEXT       "AaBbYyZz", rcOpacitySlider, 230, 54, 107, 15, SS_NOPREFIX | SS_BLACKRECT

    LTEXT       "&H:", rcHLabel, 230, 81, 8, 8
    EDITTEXT        rcH, 238, 78, 30, 14, ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    LTEXT       "&S:", rcSLabel, 230, 95, 8, 8
    EDITTEXT        rcS, 238, 92, 30, 14, ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    LTEXT       "&V:", rcVLabel, 230, 109, 8, 8
    EDITTEXT        rcV, 238, 106, 30, 14, ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE

    LTEXT       "&R:", rcRLabel, 277, 81, 8, 8
    EDITTEXT        rcRDouble, 285, 78, 30, 14, ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    EDITTEXT        rcRInt, 315, 78, 20, 14, ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    LTEXT       "&G:", rcGLabel, 277, 95, 8, 8
    EDITTEXT        rcGDouble, 285, 92, 30, 14, ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    EDITTEXT        rcGInt, 315, 92, 20, 14, ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    LTEXT       "&B:", rcBLabel, 277, 109, 8, 8
    EDITTEXT        rcBDouble, 285, 106, 30, 14, ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    EDITTEXT        rcBInt, 315, 106, 20, 14, ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    LTEXT       "&A:", rcALabel, 277, 123, 8, 8
    EDITTEXT        rcADouble, 285, 120, 30, 14, ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    EDITTEXT        rcAInt, 315, 120, 20, 14, ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE

    LTEXT       "He&x:", rcHexLabel, 269, 146, 16, 8
    EDITTEXT        rcHex, 285, 143, 50, 14, ES_LEFT | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP, WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE

    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK", IDOK, 243, 188, 45, 14, WS_GROUP
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel", IDCANCEL, 292, 188, 45, 14, WS_GROUP
END
```

Comment: You're getting rounding errors from the way dialog units are converted to pixel positions by the dialog manager. This is a common problem with dialogs - the only solution is code that manually adjusts the positions between the controls once they've been created.

Comment: Right, that's what I was fearing, though trying different font sizes didn't seem to give me a magic one that made things work (which I was hoping would happen to confirm this, so I guess I fooled myself into looking away from the right answer). Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried moving the group of HSV edit controls up by 1 DLU until the extra vertical space is between the S and V control? This would verify that the effect is really due to rounding.

Comment: No, I hadn't thought of that! It does happen (at 72,86,100). I'll keep that suggestion in mind for future dialog template related issues; thanks! As for this, I'll manually position the controls (I already need to fix up the labels by subtracting the font `TEXTMETRIC.tmInternalLeading` to get their baselines to match the edit controls's).